# Line Chart Custom X Value Accessor

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am trying to draw a line chart. The following array is not the typical data you would pass to d3js so I know I need to write a custom function to access the correct data such as `.x(function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.date)) })`. This works for an array of arrays with objects, but I can't seem to get it to work for an array of objects with a value array with objects (see `balance`). How do I write this? And is there better documentation for writing these accessors? I have been unable to find a consistent and thorough resource.

```
  var test_accounts = [
{name: "test1",
balance:
[
  {date: "2014-07-15", y: 20},
  {date: "2014-07-15", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-16", y: 40},
  {date: "2014-07-16", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-17", y: 4},
  {date: "2014-07-17", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-18", y: 30},
  {date: "2014-07-18", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-19", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-19", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-20", y: 0},
  {date: "2014-07-20", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-21", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-21", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-22", y: 80},
  {date: "2014-07-22", y: 10}
]},
{name: "test2",
balance:
[
  {date: "2014-07-15", y: 50},
  {date: "2014-07-15", y: 30},
  {date: "2014-07-16", y: 70},
  {date: "2014-07-16", y: 20},
  {date: "2014-07-17", y: 40},
  {date: "2014-07-17", y: 50},
  {date: "2014-07-18", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-18", y: 30},
  {date: "2014-07-19", y: 60},
  {date: "2014-07-19", y: 40},
  {date: "2014-07-20", y: 10},
  {date: "2014-07-20", y: 60},
  {date: "2014-07-21", y: 80},
  {date: "2014-07-21", y: 50},
  {date: "2014-07-22", y: 90},
  {date: "2014-07-22", y: 20}
]}
];

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.date)) })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
    .interpolate("linear");

// draw the line
var drawline = svg.selectAll("svg")
  .data(line1node).enter()
   .append("path")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("stroke", function(d, i) { return linecolors(i); })
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
```

Note: It is just a code snippet so I left out the scale and axis since I know those work fine.

Comment: make a fiddle, we could do something on it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you assign the path's `"d"` attribute

```
.attr("d", line)
```

`line(d)` ends up getting called for each element where `d` is its datum. `d` is expected to be an array of points.

Since you nested the array in an object, you need to instead supply a function that extracts the `balance` array:

```
.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.balance); })
```

Comment: You are a genius sir. I was so focused on that x accessor, I didn't even realize I could do that on the "d" attribute. Thanks!